# Add ID to View That Points to External Schema

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I have a pretty simple view along the lines of this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SOME_VIEW (SomeColumn, AnotherColumn, YetAnotherColumn)
AS
SELECT f.SomeColumn, f.AnotherColumn, f.YetAnotherColumn 
FROM SOME_VIEW @ SOMEURL.COM f;
```

For whatever reason, the external view doesn't include a PK which is problematic with EF combined with Oracle (in that every entity requires an `ID` column).

Now, for my purposes, I don't need to reference any PK or ID, so the field on the Entity doesn't need to have 'valid' data.

I've tried a few different things with the View to simulate that column. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SOME_VIEW (ID, SomeColumn, AnotherColumn, YetAnotherColumn) 
AS
SELECT 0 AS "ID", f.SomeColumn, AnotherColumn, YetAnotherColumn
FROM EXTERNAL_VIEW @ SOMEURL.COM f;
```

And since it's just a view I imagine I can't create the regular Sequence and Trigger for an autoincrementing value to simulate a valid `ID`.

Edit - here's more-or-less the entity class I'm trying to build (the `ID` being the only contentious field):

```
[Table("VW_SOME_VIEW")]
public class VWSOMEVIEWEntity
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("SomeColumn")]
    public string SomeColumn { get; set; }

    [Column("AnotherColumn")]
    public string AnotherColumn { get; set; }

    [Column("YetAnotherColumn")]
    public string YetAnotherColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ROWNUM pseudocolumn:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SOME_VIEW (ID, SomeColumn, AnotherColumn, YetAnotherColumn) 
AS
SELECT ROWNUM AS "ID", f.SomeColumn, AnotherColumn, YetAnotherColumn
FROM EXTERNAL_VIEW @ SOMEURL.COM f;
```